# Why doesn't setTimeout recognize function name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function( $ ){

   $.fn.hash = function(){

   function activate()
   {
      setTimeout('checkHash()', 100);
   }

   activate();

   var previousHashTag = location.hash;

   var previousHashProperty = '';

   function checkHash()
   {
     if( previousHashTag !== location.hash )
     {
        $('body').trigger("hashchange", [ getHashObj() ]);
        previousHashTag = location.hash;
        setTimeout( "checkHash()", 200);
     }
     setTimeout( "checkHash()", 100);
   }
```

This is my hash plugin I'm trying to make.
I would like to call the activate() function when user loads the plugin.
The activate function would set a timeout to check for a hash every 100 miliseconds.
How can I pull this off since checkHash is outside of the function in this object?

Comment: You should really not use string in setTimeout but directly pass the function reference : `setTimeout( checkHash, 200);`

Comment: Then how can I callback the same function in the last 2 lines with text?

Comment: Huh, sorry I don't understand your last comment... Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Then how would i use other 2 callbacks, but it's ok now. I replaced strings with function names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using string argument in `setTimeout`, which means that the code will be run in global object. As your called function is defined inside a closure of another function, you have to pass a reference

```
setTimeout(checkHash, 100);
```

or use anonymous function

```
setTimeout(function(){
  checkHash();
});
```

You have to use the second approach when you want to pass any arguments to function called from `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  checkHash(arg);
});
```

Comment: @IvanIvković I'm glad that your problem is solved :) Please accept the answer which has helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing strings to `setTimeout` and evaluating them. This breaks the normal scope. Don't do that, pass functions instead.

```
setTimeout(checkHash, 100);
```

Now scope will be preserved, and you can access `activate` from `checkHash` and vice versa as they are declared in the same scope.